# Invoke JavaScript callback from QT with structure/object argument

Tags: javascript, qt5.5

I am using QT 5.5 version.

I need to invoke javascript callback function from QT plugin with Structure/Object as argument. I could not modify HTML Application since it is not in our scope.

HTML application code snippet

```
var obj1 = document.getElementById('obj1_id'); //QT plugin object 1
var obj2 = document.getElementById('obj2_id'); //QT plugin object 2
obj2.init(obj1,callback); //QT API
function callback(arg1)
{
if ( obj1 === arg1){
// SUCCESS
else
// FAILURE
}
```

QT plugin code snippet

```
class::init(QWebElement obj, QString callback)
{
    //need to Invoke callback with obj argument
}
```

Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Using Qt Signals and Slots -

In your javascript function -

add the following line -

myoperation.alert_script_signal.connect(callback);

In the Qt framework based C++ class - constructor, add the following line -

Register your Javascript callback --

view->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("myoperation", this);

// now invoke the callback from some method in that Qt class.

emit alert_script_signal();

You need to understand one thing that QtWebkit is the platform here. So, basically, the html, javascript is running on the Qt Webkit.

I have some examples -  http://www.tune2wizard.com/linux-qt-callback-from-c-to-the-javascript-function/

Comment: Here in my requirement, I could not modify javascript function since HTML application is not in our scope